# clear multiple directories with rm

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, rm

I am trying to clear multiple directories stored in an array. Here's a simplified example (I have more directories).

```
#!/bin/bash    

$IMAGES_DIR="/Users/michael/scripts/imagefiles"
$BACKUP_DIR="/Users/michael/scripts/imagebackups"

...

array=( $IMAGES_DIR $BACKUP_DIR )
for i in ${array[@]}
do
    if [ "$(ls -A $i)" ]; then     # check that directory has files in it
        rm "$i/"*                  # remove them 
    fi
done
```

I get errors for each directory, e.g.:

> rm: /Users/michael/scripts/imagefiles/*: No such file or directory

Answer (score 4):

How about accomplishing it all in a single command?

You can capture the file existence check, globbing and removal with one `find` call. In the case of GNU's version of `find` we'd have this:

```
for f in "${array[@]}"; do
     find "$f" -type f -delete
done
```

If you don't have GNU `find` use this invocation:

```
find "$f" -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

(If instead of clearing files from the entire directory hierarchy you only want to clear files that are immediate children then add `-maxdepth 1` before `-type f`.)

**But wait, there's more....**

As [John1024 wisely notes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412749/clear-multiple-directories-with-rm/412756?noredirect=1#comment740097_412756) you can forgo the loop altogether by passing the array as the first parameter to `find`:

```
     find "${array[@]}" -type f -delete
```

That's because: *1)* `find` will accept multiple directories to be searched and processed in one execution *2)* the shell will split the array such that each element (directory) becomes an individual positional parameter to `find`.

Comment: Simpler: `find "${array[@]}"  -type f -delete`

Comment: Good one @John1024 ... I shoulda thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash    

IMAGES_DIR="/Users/michael/scripts/imagefiles"
BACKUP_DIR="/Users/michael/scripts/imagebackups"

array=( $IMAGES_DIR $BACKUP_DIR )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    if [ "$(ls -A "$i")" ]; then     
        rm "${i:?}"/*                 
    fi
done
```

Errors:

1. Placing `$` on the left hand side of variable assignments
2. Not quoting the `$i` in `if [ "$(ls -A $i)" ];then`
3. Use `"${var:?}"` to ensure this, `rm "$i/"*` never expands to `/*`

Answer (score 0):

The `-f` option to `rm` makes the utility not complain if the file operands do not exist.  It would also not exit with a failure.

What's *possibly* happening in your case is that one or several of the directories are empty apart from files or directories with hidden names, so the `*` at the end of your pattern isn't expanded to anything. You can make the `*` glob match hidden names in `bash` by setting the `dotglob` shell option.

You also should not put `$` on variable names in assignments, and you need to double quote variable expansions to avoid word splitting and filename generation (globbing).  Variable names should be lower case so that you don't inadvertently clobber environment variables or special shell variables.

Alternative formulation of your code that takes these things into account;

```bash
#!/bin/bash    

shopt -s dotglob

images_dir="/Users/michael/scripts/imagefiles"
backup_dir="/Users/michael/scripts/imagebackups"

dirs=( "$images_dir" "$backup_dir" )

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    rm -f "$dir"/*
done
```

The above would try to remove all files from the directories. If the directories have subdirectories, you'll get errors from `rm` regarding this.  Would you want to delete these too, use `-r` with `rm`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call an external process to check, but use the shell internal function *test*

> if test -d "$i"; then    # check that directory exists

Between the test and the call to *rm* it is possible other processes already wiped the directory out,
so the *rm* will fail.
You can use the switch *-f* or redirects the errors

> /bin/rm "$i/*" 2> /dev/null     # remove the files

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to remove all files in an array of folders, another alternative would be to pass in the array in `rm` like so:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash    

$IMAGES_DIR="/Users/michael/scripts/imagefiles"
$BACKUP_DIR="/Users/michael/scripts/imagebackups"

# ...

# to preserve whitespaces in path strings, add double quotes around each variable
array=( "$IMAGES_DIR" "$BACKUP_DIR" )

# this appends "/*" to the end of each dirname if you want to delete the contents of the directories
# without deleting the directories themselves
array=( "${array[@]/%//*}" )

# this will spread the array into multiple calls to rm
rm -rf ${array[@]}
```

One-liner example:

```bsh
rm -rf ${array[@]/%//*}
```

But if you want to delete the folders as well, you can just use

```bsh
rm -rf ${array[@]}
```

One difference to note with [B Layer's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412756/374033), is that while `find` will print any errors in finding the paths provided, `rm` will not in this example.

EDIT:

as [kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) pointed out, it's important to note that spreading the array like this could be dangerous if there are whitespaces or shell-globbing characters in you paths. To avoid splitting the array by these characters, make sure to add double quotes around the variables added to the array.

Comment: Note that using the expansion of `array` would split it on whitespaces as well as expand any _other_ shell globbing characters in the pathname (apart from the `*` that you add to the end).

Answer (score -2):

Please find the below awk oneliner   to achieve the same , As tested it worked fine

---

```
i="/root/";ls -ltr /root/| grep "^-rw" | awk -v i="$i" '{print "rm -rvf" " " i$9}' | sh
```

---

for example i have assigned variable i = path /root/ you can change as per your requirement

i="/root/" ===> path

Comment: See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @steeldriver As cross verified from above command I am getting the same result let me know if there is any difference in output

Comment: This would fail on any file whose name contains whitespace or backslashes. Also, since you're removing _files_ (not directories), why are you using `-r` with `rm`?